# Is $T_n(R) \cong T_n(R)^{op}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $T_n(R)$ be the ring of $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices.  Is $T_n(R) \cong T_n(R)^{op}$?

I have already shown that $M_n(R)^{op} \cong M_n(R^{op})$ (regardless of whether $R$ is commutative), by mapping $A \mapsto A^t$ (the transpose).

My thinking is that since $T_n(R) \subset M_n(R)$ and $M_n(R)^{op} \cong M_n(R^{op})$, that we will have $T_n(R)^{op} \cong T_n(R^{op})$.  Then, since $R$ is commutative, $R^{op} \cong R$.  So, we get: $T_n(R^{op}) \cong T_n(R)$, which would give the result.

I'm not sure this is right though, because:

-I can't construct an explicit isomorphism,

-The isomorphism on matrices maps a matrix to its transpose.  This map does not send upper-triangular matrices to upper triangular matrices, which makes me worry my logic is flawed.  (Though if upper triangular matrices are isomorphic to lower triangular matrices, then I guess this is fine?)

-It seems a bit too easy compared to other questions I'm being set. :P

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the automorphism is $(a_{ij}) \mapsto (b_{ij})$ where
$$b_{ij} = a_{(n-j+1),(n-i+1)}$$
corresponding to switching entries symmetrically with respect to the 'other diagonal' of the matrix (not the usual diagonal, but the other one).

Then rows become column and viceversa, and being upper triangular is preserved, and products row-by column are preserved.

For example in the $2 \times 2$ case we have
$$\left( \begin{matrix} a &b \\ 0&c \end{matrix} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} A &B \\ 0&C \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} aA &aB+bC \\ 0&cC \end{matrix} \right)$$
and
$$\left( \begin{matrix} C &B \\ 0&A \end{matrix} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} c &b \\ 0&a \end{matrix} \right) =
\left( \begin{matrix} cC &aB+bC \\ 0&aA \end{matrix} \right)$$